# Passing a string column name to a function with groupby_() and mutate in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I v'e been stuck on this error where I'm sending the column names that I want to group by, the column name to sum up, and the new column name to place these results to a function that does this. But I keep getting this error where it sums the whole column instead of looking at the certain criteria, but if I changed colName1 to the actual column name it works properly.

My code looks like this:

```
results <- MACO

DANG <- function(dF, colGroupName1, colName1, newColName){
  dF %>%
    group_by_(colGroupName1) %>%
    mutate(!!newColName := sum(dF[[colName1]]))
}

results <- DANG(results,"Open.Geo","ACT.Volume","Sum.Criteria")
```

[In this picture my code gives me the left results (incorrect) but I need to get the right results:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y4oZ.png)

I've been reading all this stuff about quoting but Im unsure to how to approach this situation.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need `group_by_at` which can take string as input.  also, the 'colName1' can be converted to a symbol with `sym` and then evaluate (`!!`)

```
DANG <- function(dF, colGroupName1, colName1, newColName){
 dF %>%
     group_by_at(vars(colGroupName1)) %>%
     mutate(!!newColName :=  sum(!! rlang::sym(colName1)))
   }


results <- DANG(results, "Open.Geo", "ACT.Volume", "Sum.Criteria")
```

Comment: Why not also use `mutate_at`?

Comment: @thc`  `mutate_at` can be used and is more general when there are more than 1 column.  Here, the OP's function is interested only in a single column

Comment: Sorry, my comment was more addressed to the `rlang::sym` usage, perhaps `mutate_at` is not the right verb.  I don't understand the usage in this case, and it doesn't seem to calculate the sum of the group, which is what the user wanted.  Is it really necessary?

Comment: @thc You are right.  I forgot to paste the `sum`.  If your doubt is why we need to load another package `rlang`, there is not much need.  I was just replying to rectify the code OP used.  Instead it can be `mutate_at(vars(colName1), sum)`  But there is an issue with column name, `mutate_at` can add a suffix to the column name, but to change it to a custom column name, then we need another `rename`

Comment: Thanks Akrun, you helped me out so much. I was stuck on this issue for a while!